# Periodogram explained

Tags: frequency, signal-processing, spectral-analysis

If I plot a periodogram of let's say `sin(20x) + 2sin(80x)` and it looks like this:

[image: periodogram]

What does it say, i.e., how do I interpret this periodogram? How could I compute the values in the graph by hand from `sin(20x) + 2sin(80x)`? I don't understand how to get from `sin(20x) + 2sin(80x)` to the periodogram. 
This was plotted in R using `periodogram()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Periodogram is used to estimate **power spectral density**(PSD) of a signal, which allows you to calculate how much power it contains given a frequency or frequency band. Frequencies with higher peaks imply that the signal has a strong(dominant) sinusoidal component with exactly the same frequency. In your plot, $f \approx 0.28$ seems to be the most important frequency component of your signal.

To compute PSD by hand at plot it , one way is to compute the Fourier transform of the auto-correlation function of your signal.